# Responsively animating a booth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an animated trade show booth where clients can pick from options on the right, and they fly in and create the image posted below.

[image]

I've successfully gotten this to work on a certain size monitor, but it is not responsive. I've had a good amount of experience with responsive design, but am unsure the best method to create this design responsively given that the animations are flying in from various hidden divs.

Here is a link to the starter file: http://barret.co/resources/build-a-booth/index.html

Here is a sample of the code:
HTML:

```
<aside>
        <h1>Let's build a booth!</h1><br>

        <h2>Select your pieces <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></h2>
        <hr>
            <ul>
               <li><span id="1">Back Wall <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></li>
               <li><span id="6">Banner <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></li>
               <li><span id="2">Desk <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></li>
               <li><span id="3">Left Rail <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></li>
               <li><span id="4">Right Rail <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></li>
               <li><span id="5">Chairs <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></li>
           </ul>    
        </aside>

        <div id="holder-top">
            <div id="banner"><img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="holder-left">
            <div id="back-wall"><img src="images/back-wall.png" alt="back-wall"></div>
            <div id="left-rail"><img src="images/left-rail.png" alt="left-rail"></div>
            <div id="chairs"><img src="images/chairs.png" alt="chairs"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="holder-right">
            <div id="desk"><img src="images/desk.png" alt="desk"></div>
            <div id="right-rail"><img src="images/right-rail.png" alt="right-rail"></div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
}


aside span{
cursor:pointer;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size:28px;
}

h1{
font-size:32px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

h2{
font-size:26px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
}

#showcase{
width:100%;
height:900px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,.85);
}

aside{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
width:320px;
height:100%;
padding:20px;
background:blue;
color:white;
}

#back-wall{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
opacity:.2;
}

#desk{
position:absolute;
top:300px;
opacity:.2;
}

#left-rail{
position:absolute;
top:271px;
opacity:.2;
}

#right-rail{
position:absolute;
top:271px;
opacity:.2;
}

#chairs{
position:absolute;
top:430px;
opacity:.2;
z-index:99;
}

#banner{
position:absolute;
opacity:.2;
z-index:99;
}

#holder-left{
left:-550px;
position:absolute;
top:101px;
height:100%;
}

#holder-right{
right:-550px;
position:absolute;
top:101px;
height:100%;
}

#holder-top{
position:absolute;
top:-240px;
z-index:9999;
left:622px;
}
```

JS:
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
var a=0;
    $("#1").click(function(){
        $("#back-wall").stop().animate({
            left: ++a%2*1150,
            opacity:'1',
             }, 'slow');
    });  

    var b=0;
    $("#2").click(function(){
        $("#desk").stop().animate({
            right: ++b%2*1460,
            opacity:'1',
             }, 'slow');
    });  

    var c=0;
    $("#3").click(function(){
        $("#left-rail").stop().animate({
            left: ++c%2*1150,
            opacity:'1',
             }, 'slow');
    });  

    var d=0;
    $("#4").click(function(){
        $("#right-rail").stop().animate({
            right: ++d%2*1345,
            opacity:'1',
             }, 'slow');
    });  

    var e=0;
    $("#5").click(function(){
        $("#chairs").stop().animate({
            left: ++e%2*1300,
            opacity:'1',
             }, 'slow');
    });  
    var f=0;
    $("#6").click(function(){
        $("#banner").stop().animate({
            top: ++f%2*370,
            opacity:'1',
             }, 'slow');
    });  

}); // ready method
```

Any help is very much appreciated and thanks in advance!

On a side note, I am using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) for the "+" icons in the top right. I was trying to also figure out once clicked, if the icon could be changed to their "-" icon. This is less important but if anyone knows, I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks again!

Comment: You should probably be more specific about what you need help with - you'll get more accurate answers.

Comment: How was that not specific? I asked how to make the images fly in responsively into a container.

Comment: I kind of expected there's more to it. Anyway, using percentages instead of pixels is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your items are positioned relatively to the window size. Instead you need to add a wrapper of some sort and make it relative to the wrapper.

Wrap all the items in a div and center align in. Then position all your items outside of the wrapper. You can make the wrapper a percentage width if you want it to be responsive.

Hope that somewhat helps.

Comment: +1 and probably everything should be in percentages.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this as soon as I get another chance. I figured it was something like that, should I make the wrapper position relative and position it x amount of pixels to the left of the visible screen and make it large enough for it to slide into?